# Use a varible to select a Firebase Path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, variables, angularfire2

I have a problem with selecting a path with a variable to a Firebase Database.

I am using using this:

```
 constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase) { }

 this.af.object('/restaurant' + key).query.once('value').then(data => {console.log("ISTOOOOO",data.val());});
```

the key value is this: 'testemodel@ola100_pt'

but the problem is that to access that path i need it to be "/testemodel@ola100_pt".

I always used variables to get to the paths, but now i cant seem to using them, because it always needs the "/".

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can build the path by adding the required `/` yourself after "restaurant":

```
this.af.object('/restaurant/' + key)...
```

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to be more clear about what the problem is with the code you've written.  Or just add the `/` as I suggested.